# Comparing 4 variables using single if statement

Tags: shell-script, wildcards

I am preparing one script to compare 4 variables using single if statement.

Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
a="abc"
b="abc"
c="deftdgr"
d="def"
if [[ $a = $b && $d =  ]]
then
    echo "inside if loop"
    break
else
    echo "inside else loop"
fi
```

My question is: 
is there any way i can use any wildcard to compare `$d` and `$c` so that tge `if` statement returns true value. And output comes as "inside if loop"?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want, but yes, you can use wildcards on the right-hand side of `=` to do pattern matching. `[[ foo = f* ]]`, for example, would return true since the string `foo` matches the pattern `f*`. Likewise, `[[ $c = $d* ]]` would return true.

Comment: @chepner, in which case, you probably want `$c = "$d"*` so that the contents of `$d` are not taken as a pattern.

Comment: @utkarsh, what are the complete criteria for success? Is it "(a equals b) and (c startswith d)"? Can you be completely specific?

Comment: @glenn jackman - it should be like (a equals b ) and ( d should match everything starting with def [i.e. something like $d = $c*]) . Am i clear a bit?

Comment: ... so you don't really need $c at all then? `if [[ $a = "$b" && $d == def* ]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your if condition like below:-

```
#!/bin/bash
a="abc"
b="abc"
c="deftdgr"
d="def"
if [[ $a = "$b" && $c == "$d"* ]]
then
    echo "inside if loop"
    #break you don't need this at all
else
    echo "inside else loop"
fi
```

Comment: Working fine as expected... Thanks alot for quick response.. :)

Comment: One more question. Can we use multiple and operators in single if statement?

Answer (score 1):

This is called the logical `AND`, logical operator.

```
exp1 -a  exp2 returns true if both exp1 and exp2 are true.
```

If you are comapring strings, you do:

```
  if [[ condition1 && condition2 ]]; then  echo "blah" ; fi
```

One way to express this:

```
if [[ "$a" == "$b" && "$a" == "$c" ]]
```

When comaparing numbers, you do:

```
  if (( (a == b) && (a == c) )); then echo "blah" ; fi
```

Doc [click](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)